# Read Access Violation When Trying to Access Dynamically Allocated Member Variable with Member Function

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a class called person which has a pointer to an array of ints which is dynamically allocated with the "new" keyword in the constructor. However, when I attempt to access this array through the pointer from a member function, "person::getval", I receive a read access violation.Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong? I think it may have something to do with scope, because if I access the "numlist" array from inside the constructor there are no issues. Thanks.

person.h

```
    class person {
public:
    person();
    person(int length);
    ~person();
    int getval(int a);
    void setval(int a, int b);
private:
    int* numlist;
    int listlength;
    int age;

};
```

person.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "person.h"

person::person() {
    person(4);
}
person::person(int length){
    age = 16;
    numlist = new int[length];
    listlength = length;
    for (int k = 0; k < length; k++) {
        numlist[k] = 0;
    }
}
person::~person() {
    delete[] numlist;
}
int person::getval(int a) {
    return *(numlist + a);          //READ ACCESS VIOLATION OCCURS HERE
}

void person::setval(int position, int val) {
    *(numlist + position) = val;
}
```

main

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "person.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    person mark;
    cout << mark.getval(1)<<endl;
    int x;      //hold output
    cin >> x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this: `person(4);` It's not doing what you think it's doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
person::person() {
    person(4);
}
```

You are creating a temporary person and not doing anything with it, not calling the constructor on yourself.  You really want this:

```
person::person() : person(4) {}
```

Comment: What exactly is going on in the corrected version you posted? I haven't seen that syntax before.

Comment: "Initialization list"

Answer (score 0):

Your default constructor is not doing what you think it's doing.

```
person::person() {
    person(4);
}
```

I'm guessing you think the above default constructor is initializing the `person` instance with an array of size `4`. However, `person(4)` is creating a temporary object instance in the body of the constructor that goes out of scope and gets destroyed at the end of the constructor's body. This leaves the default constructed `person` object with an array that has not been dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 0):

```
person mark;
```

calls the `person()` constructor. I have listed this constructor below:

```
person::person() {
    person(4);
}
```

It creates a temporary anonymous variable of type `person` created with the `person(int length);` constructor. This anonymous person is destroyed upon returning from the `person()` constructor, leaving `mark` effectively uninitialized.

Therefore the `person` created and destroyed while creating `mark` had storage allocated for `numlist`. `mark` got jack, so `mark.getval(1)`, below

```
int person::getval(int a) {
    return *(numlist + a);
}
```

adds `a` to an uninitialized `numlist`  and then attempted to access the memory at the resulting unknown address. Undefined Behaviour hi-jinks ensue.